# How to display 10 numbers per line? -Beginner-

Tags: java, arrays, jcreator

I am currently working on a program involving arrays and I have generated 200 random numbers ranging between 0-100. But I cannot display all the numbers, 10 per line. This is my current code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random ();

        for(int i=0; i<200; i++){
            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println("Generated 200 random numbers: " + randomNumber);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `System.out.println()` prints what you tell it, and moves to the next line.
- `System.out.print()`, however, prints stuff and stays on the same line. Next call to `System.out.print()` will continue on the same line.

Play with that.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can possibly use arrays to display the numbers on one line?

Comment: Yup. If you call `System.out.print()` in a loop, it'll print things out into the same line

Answer (score -3):

you basically need two loops, the outside loop goes through [0-200), and the internal loop prints out 10 numbers per line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
   {
     System.out.print(randomNumber + " ");
   }
   System.out.print("\n");  // change to a new line
}
```

Comment: The reason this gets down voted - don't provide complete solutions to homeworks, help people learn. In your case, the solution is also wrong, as it prints out 2000 numbers.